# Getting "DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147467259" while deploying wp8.1 app on emulator

Tags: .net, xamarin, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am using Visual studio 2015 enterprise edition. My mobile application was developed in windows phone 8.1 platform using visual studio 2013 enterprise edition. Recently i installed visual studio 2015 and tried to run my app in emulator. But unfortunately i am getting below error though there is no build error. Any one has any idea how to get rid off this?

DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147467259

Comment: can you share your SDK version and the emulator version?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My SDK version is Windows Phone 8.1. Emulator is "Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB"